# Start foreach loop in reverse order

Tags: asp.net

```
public DataTable ReverseOrder(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                duplicateList.Add(drow);
            else
                hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
        }
}
```

I want to start for each loop in reverse (Descending) order.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Enumerable.Reverse` (if that is what you want):

```
public DataTable ReverseOrder(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
    return dTable.AsEnumerable().Reverse().CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: So the foreach could be written as `foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.AsEnumerable().Reverse().CopyToDataTable().Rows)`

Answer (score 2):

For such cases for(;;;) comes handy. I believe foreach wont work. Even if it work you need lot a workarounds. So its time considering for() loop , since it works on the indexes.

In your case

```
int count = dTable.Rows.Count;
for(int i=count-1;i<=0;i--)
{
  //logic
}
```

### Update:

Tims answer is far better than illustrated by me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
List<DataRow> rows = dTable.AsEnumerable().Reverse().ToList();
foreach (DataRow drow in rows)
{
    if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
        duplicateList.Add(drow);
    else
        hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From analyzing your code, it looks like your simplest answer would be to use an intermediate list to collect the results from your foreach loop, reverse it, then add that reversed list to your "htable".  Foreach cannot be run in reverse (though a for loop with reverse iteration could be).

The code would look something like this:

```
    public DataTable ReverseOrder(DataTable dTable, string colName)
    {
        List<DataRow> intermediateDuplicateList = new List<DataRow>();
        List<DataRow> intermediateHTableAddList = new List<DataRow>();
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                intermediateDuplicateList.Add(drow);
            else
                intermediateHTableAddList.Add(drow);
        }

        intermediateDuplicateList.Reverse();
        intermediateHTableAddList.Reverse();

        //appending the reversed list to dupelist.
        duplicateList.AddRange(intermediateDuplicateList);

        //iterating through a reversed list adding to hTable;
        foreach (DataRow d in intermediateHTableAddList)
        {
            hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tim's answer is more direct, uses less memory, and is more efficient.  If you don't care about any of those - use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use For-Next loop, For-Each cannot be run in reverse:

```
Function ArraySum(Numbers As Variant)
    Summed = 0
    For Number = (Numbers.Rows.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
        Summed = Summed + Numbers.Cells(Number + 1, 1)
    Next Number
    ArraySum = Summed
End Function
```